# Display .txt file in an HTML web page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Here is what I have so far I need to use a .txt file as I have a node js app powering it that relies on it also I am using the .ejs file extension for the HTML code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Currnet button count</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      <p><iframe src="count.txt" frameborder="0" height="400"
          width="95%"></iframe></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That’s way off... look into the fs module of node.js...

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org). Create a file, `file.js`:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.readFile('count.txt', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        http.createServer(function(req, res) {
            res.write(data);
        }).listen(8080);
    }
});
```

When you run this using the shell command:

```
node file.js
```

Then you can go to `http://localhost:8080` and it will be displayed there.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me how can I default the user to this page?

Comment: Do you have `NodeJS` installed?

Comment: Yes, I start the web app in the index.js file.

Comment: That...doesn't sound like Node. Sounds like Electron

Comment: It's node I can assure you. I have express and ejs installed. Not trying to sound mean.

Comment: OK then. What is the problem - does running the file work? Does it throw any errors? Maybe change `throw err;` to `console.log(err);`, look in the terminal/command line, and see what happens

Comment: It doesn't throw an error or anything it just sits there loading.

Comment: Your node or express or whatever might be broken. That code I posted works perfectly for me though

Comment: Is there a way I can reinstall those dependencies?

Comment: Just look on the website

Comment: @TrgritTjforce No problem! If my answer fixed your problem, could you please mark it as accepted by clicking on the grey tick mark to the left of my answer?

Comment: Well even if you can't make it run, my code fixed your problem, and marking it as accepted will be useful for others who are having the same problem, as they'll see the tick meaning that I fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.readFile('count.txt', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  else {
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.write(data);
        res.end()
    }).listen(8080);
}
});
```

Adding this fixed it

```
res.end()
```